# How to disable the touch "diamond" symbol in Windows for a C++ application?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, touch, windows-embedded

Windows shows an own kind of "mouse cursor" when using a touch screen: This is a small diamond-like icon which only shows up when using touch, not when using the mouse.

I would like to disable this icon for my C++ application, so I can give this kind of feedback via the "pressed" coloring of a button instead of this icon, making my application look the same way it does on other operating systems.

Comment: This is the kind of idea that people have when they imagine that their users will user their program alone and never use another program. Your program, whilst I'm sure it is excellent, is not so great that it will be used exclusively. Unless you are writing an OS yourself, you really don't want to be doing this. Way to confuse the user. One set of UI feedback for your app, and another for all the other apps. You are expected to work with the system, not against it. Work with the system and your app will be easier to use.

Comment: @David: The advice is in general true. However, if you consider embedded systems, for example, where a device will generally only ever run a single application, a custom UI is fairly common, and can in fact become more intuitive by violating *established standards*. The touch input cursor was invented when input was possible with a stylus only. With true touch input, it is usually fully hidden behind the finger touching the surface, and providing different interaction feedback feels a lot more natural.

Comment: @IInspectable OK, I grant you that. In a sense then, an embedded system is similar to an OS because you are in control of the entire experience.

Comment: @David: In most cases you are of course correct. However, as IInspectable correctly assumes, I am developing for an embedded device and want to create a platform-independent, intuitive behavior.